# Generate a new text file each button click

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook, file

I'm currently working on an application integrated into Facebook in which a user is able to enter some information into a form, click a button and the information selected in the form is written to a text file.

The next screen allows them to both download the text file as well as post it to Facebook to be shared with other people.

The problem I have is that it will only work for one person. If someone creates a file, downloads it and chooses to post it to Facebook... When another user creates a new file... The existing one will be overwritten, meaning the file the previous user created was lost if they didn't download it.

I looked online and found some code to generate a random string of characters which might be of some use but I lost as to what I should do next...

Can anyone shed any light on the subject?

Thanks.

Comment: You post with the mysql tag. Why don't you just save the messages in the database and only create the file when the user actually wants do download it?!

Comment: Seems fairly straightforward, but I'm a novice PHP developer. I'll give it a try. Thanks again for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to generate unique names : http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

You gotta call each text file a different name.  You could use the `uniqid` function.

Additionally, because you are in Facebook you could also consider using the users Facebook user id - these are also unique to each user.

Using the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) you can retrieve the users unique Facebook id by calling this method :

`$facebook->getUser()`
*You will need to ensure that you have authenticated the user to retrieve the information*

Using the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you can simply make a call to :

`FB.api("/me?fields=id")`